# API's to extract 7z files in .net

Tags: .net, extract, 7zip

Is there any API available, that can be used in .net that can read/extract 7z files ?

Comment: You're opposed to calling out to the executable directly?  You could also wrap the C API and expose it to managed code.

Answer (score 5):

I don't believe there's any "built-in" .NET library for it, but, right at the source you can get the [**LZMA SDK**](http://www.7-zip.org/sdk.html), which include full C# source code for 7z compression and decompression.

Answer (score 3):

Use http://www.codeplex.com/sevenzipsharp